# Update a column based on a join when the key has multiple entry in the other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which I have to update column based on a join to another table. The problem however is that the key is not unique in the other table so the join returns more than one value . I am a newbie and cant think of what might be a solution to it. I tried a normal update based on a join but it returns error saying the subquery returns multiple values) Please help! 
(I am working on Oracle )
eg
 Table A

```
ID|pc       
 1|         
 2|         
 3|         
 4|
```

Table B

```
Id|pc
 1|a            
 1|b
```

I need the table to look like this after the update.
Table - A

```
ID    pc            
 1     a            
 1     b            
 2              
 3              
 4
```

Comment: You're not only updating TableA, but also inserting a new record.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes. That is the intention. I am sorry if the question seems unclear. Is there a way the result can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, because the main reference you've got is the id, but for the matched id, you will need to both update a record and insert a record.

This will do the trick for the specified data, but note that you cannot run this query more than once. As soon as the information is merged into TableA, this query will not be able to update it again. Maybe there are ways to do that as well, but since the given problem is quite abstract, I don't know what would be the best solution.

```
merge into TableA a
using
 (select id, pc, dense_rank() over (partition by id, order by pc) as nr
  from tableB) b
on (b.id = a.id and b.nr = 1)
when matched then
  update set a.pc = b.pc
when not matched then
  insert(id, pc) values (b.id, b.pc)
```

Alternatively, you can define a PL/SQL program block to update this data. Then you could use cursors or a collection of statements to update the table, which is probably easier, more flexible and more readable that trying to write a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The question definitely is way above beginner level (for me) unlike what I thought. :)

Comment: Two issues: `DENSE_RANK` can produce multiple rows with the same rank if they have identical values and this may trigger multiple updates of the same row - switching to `ROW_NUMBER` can solve this; and if `Table_A` already has a non-null `pc` value then the match will overwrite it with the first ranked `pc` value from `Table_B`.

Comment: Good point about dense_rank. I guess I assumed by the question that the combination of id/pc was unique in TableB.

Answer (score 0):

If the `pc` values in `Table_B` are unique and the initial values in `Table_A` are either `NULL` or not duplicates of `Table_B` values then GolezTrol's method will work fine. However, if there are duplicate values in `Table_B` or between the two tables then try this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93fd/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A (ID NUMBER(1),pc CHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE Table_B (ID NUMBER(1),pc CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO Table_A
          SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, NULL FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO Table_B
          SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'c' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

The first `ROW_NUMBER` handles inserting non-matched rows (even if there are multiple copies of the same values).

The second `ROW_NUMBER` handles inserting duplicates of existing values - if `Table_A` already contains (ID.x, pc.y) and `Table_B` contains multiple duplicates of that value then the first value will be overwritten and subsequent duplicates from `Table_B` will be appended.

```
MERGE INTO Table_A dst
USING (SELECT ID,
              pc,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY pc) AS rn,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, pc ORDER BY pc) AS rnx
       FROM   Table_B) src
ON (     dst.ID = src.ID
    AND (   (dst.pc = src.pc AND src.rnx = 1)
         OR (dst.pc IS NULL  AND src.rn = 1)
        )
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dst.pc = src.pc
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, pc) VALUES (src.ID, src.pc)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93fd/2/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A ORDER BY ID, pc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93fd/2/1)**:

```
| ID |     PC |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      a |
|  1 |      b |
|  2 |      a |
|  2 |      b |
|  2 |      c |
|  3 |      a |
|  3 |      a |
|  3 |      a |
|  4 | (null) |
```